# Obtain points at beginning/ending of visual line without using vertical-motion

Tags: mouse

**Q**:  How to obtain the points at the beginning and ending of each visual line of the current window -- *without* using `vertical-motion` -- when `word-wrap` is `t` (aka `visual-line-mode`).

For this experiment, I am using a few of the functions from the section of the manual entitled **Accessing Mouse Events**:  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Accessing-Mouse.html

BACKGROUND:  As we all know, `vertical-motion` is very costly in terms of time.  I have a custom minor-mode that is similar to `vline.el` -- http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/vline.el -- except that mine works with `word-wrap`/`visual-line-mode`.  I am searching for a faster method to perform calculations each command loop.  At the present time, I make one pass of the current window (every command loop) using `vertical-motion` to obtain the following information:  point at beginning/ending of the whole line; point at the beginning/ending of the visual line; the visual column number at the end of the visual line (which may be different than the actual column number when a line is wrapped at the window edge); point at each location in a vertical line from the cursor position spanning from window-start to window-end; and, various other information based on all of the foregoing -- e.g., colors of foreground/background faces and character codes at the various locations, line numbers, etc.

```lisp
(setq word-wrap t)

(setq truncate-lines nil)

(progn
  (remove-overlays) ;; after-string properties prevent `posn-at-point` from working right.
  (let* (
      pt
      posn-at-x-y
      (counter 0)
      (window-height (window-height))
      (window-header-line-height (window-header-line-height))
      (frame-char-height (frame-char-height))
      (position (posn-at-point))
      (posn-x-y (nth 2 position))
      (posn-actual-col-row (nth 6 position)))
    (while (<= counter window-height)
      (unless
          (and
            (= counter 0)
            (= 0 window-header-line-height))
        (setq posn-at-x-y (posn-at-x-y (car posn-x-y) (* frame-char-height counter))))
      (setq pt (nth 1 posn-at-x-y))
      (setq counter (1+ counter))
      (message "counter: %s | %s" counter (if (integerp pt) (char-after pt) pt)))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First Rough Draft**

As to `x`, one pixel less than the `(window-body-width nil t)` when used in conjunction with `posn-at-x-y` will yield the point at the end of the visual line.  As to `x`, zero will return the point at the beginning of the visual line.  Refer to the diagram in the manual at the section relating to *window sizes*:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Sizes.html

```lisp
(progn
  (remove-overlays)
  (let* (
      pt
      posn-at-x-y
      (counter 0)
      (window-body-width (window-body-width nil t))
      (last-available-x (1- window-body-width))
      (window-height (window-height))
      (window-header-line-height (window-header-line-height))
      (frame-char-height (frame-char-height))
      (position (posn-at-point))
      (posn-x-y (nth 2 position))
      (posn-actual-col-row (nth 6 position)) ) ;; not presently used
    (while (<= counter window-height)
      (unless
          (and
            (= counter 0)
            (= 0 window-header-line-height))
        (setq posn-at-x-y (posn-at-x-y (car posn-x-y) (* frame-char-height counter)))
        (setq posn-x-y (nth 2 posn-at-x-y)))
      (setq pt (nth 1 posn-at-x-y))
      (message "counter: %s | pt: %s | pbovl: %s | peovl: %s"
        counter
        (if (integerp pt)
          pt ;; (char-after pt) -- not presently used.
          pt)
        (nth 1 (posn-at-x-y 0
          (if (= counter 0)
            (cdr posn-x-y)
            (+ window-header-line-height (cdr posn-x-y)))))
        (nth 1 (posn-at-x-y last-available-x
          (if (= counter 0)
            (cdr posn-x-y)
            (+ window-header-line-height (cdr posn-x-y))))))
      (setq counter (1+ counter)))))
```